# Autocomplete and send a form with R and Rvest

Tags: r, forms, rvest

I've being looking a lot before coming here.

I want to autocomplete a form and send it with R using Rvest library.

This is the form: https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/shpCarburantes/

I know the problem are the names, but I can't find the correct ones.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance!

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/shpCarburantes/"
form <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_form()
set_values(form, 
      "ctl00$cph_Contenido$ddlTipoConsulta" = "0",
      "ctl00$cph_Contenido$ddlTipoTemp" = "0",
      "ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaInicial" = "01/12/2018",
      "ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaFinal" = "30/12/2018"
      )

Error: Unknown field names: ctl00$cph_Contenido$ddlTipoConsulta, 
ctl00$cph_Contenido$ddlTipoTemp, ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaInicial, 
ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaFinal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `html_form()` is a list of forms, not a single form. The function `set_values()` expects a single form, so you will need to extract the form before calling it:

```
form <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_form()
form <- form[[1]]

set_values(form, 
  "ctl00$cph_Contenido$ddlTipoConsulta" = "0",
  "ctl00$cph_Contenido$ddlTipoTemp" = "0",
  "ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaInicial" = "01/12/2018",
  "ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaFinal" = "30/12/2018"
  )
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks, the problem I have now is that I'm not able to send the form and here I know I'm doing something wrong but no what... I'm very new with R and web scrapping and all help will be very appreciated.

     {submit_form(session = session_url, form = send_form, submit = 
     "ctl00$cph_Contenido$BtnAniadir")
     Error: Unknown submission name 'ctl00$cph_Contenido$BtnAniadir'.
     Possible values: ctl00$BtnOKInfoInstalaciones, 
     ctl00$cph_Contenido$txtFechaInicial}
The name is correct, but it seems that my code is not able to "see" it